# Changes in POSIX 2013 revision

Tags: posix, standards

According to the [POSIX FAQ](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/papers/posix_faq.html), the standard has been revised and ratified by IEEE in 2013.

What changed from the previous standard, from 2008?

Answer (score 5):

According to the abstract in the [online edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/),

> POSIX.1-2008 is simultaneously IEEE Std 1003.1™-2008 and The Open Group Technical Standard Base Specifications, Issue 7. This 2013 Edition includes IEEE Std 1003.1-2008/Cor 1-2013 incorporated into IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (the base document). The 2013 edition incorporates Technical Corrigendum 1 addressing problems discovered since the approval of the 2008 edition.

Technical Corrigendum 1, containing the change-set as a big, disorganized "patch," is [freely available](http://webstore.iec.ch/corrigenda/iso/isoiecieee9945-cor1%7Bed1.0%7Den.pdf) from IEC. It appears that most if not all changes can also be browsed in their bug tracker by querying attached bugs to the [tc1-2008 tag](http://austingroupbugs.net/tag_view_page.php?tag_id=7). A quick glance shows minor clarifications and changes covering everything from regular expressions to the filesystem to `setjmp`.