# Does POSIX have a change log?

Tags: posix

Is there a document detailing what has been changed from one POSIX version to another?  I am looking for something, in a tabular view, that details what changed from say version 2004 to 2008

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781247/changes-in-posix-2013-revision

Comment: Doesn't answer my question about a change log.  Per's response seems to be the most accurate.

Comment: it doesn't answer it because there is no single changelog. So the closest you will get is to read each sections change history as Per suggest - which cover major changes + every individual documentation page. Or go through the bugzilla entries, which covers every change and/or inspect the technical corrigendums - which the other question suggests.

Comment: @Dan The bug tracker database is exactly a log of every individual tiny change. The process of each change is logged in the tracked bugs. It's not clear what else you might be looking for. The rationales mentioned by Per only list added and removed interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. There's the [Rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/contents.html), one section per volume. Search for "Change History".

Unless I missed something, there doesn't seem to be a way to see what changed except for what was added or removed, except by visiting the page of each function/utility/etc.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the other Q&A, you can start at [the tag](http://austingroupbugs.net/tag_view_page.php?tag_id=7) representing a particular POSIX revision and then click "attached issues." Due to the way the Mantis webapp handles URLs, I cannot provide a link directly to the issues list.

I don't know whether they compile the database into a single text file; I don't see the advantage as the bug tracker database is already searchable.